# can a mongoose schema field reference more than one other models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema field called "bookmarks" and I would like it to reference more than one model. for example, if I have 2 other models named "post" and "complain". I would like the user to be able to bookmark both of them.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    bookmarks: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: false,
        ref: 'Post'
    }],
})
```

below is a post model, where users can post things in general

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    }
})
```

below is a complain model, where users can post a complain

```
const complainSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    }
})
```

How can I get the bookmarks field in the user model to be able to get the object id of both the complain model and the post model?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest those two models in userSchema itself just like you are doing with bookmark schema .
You can also refer to this link , i hope it will resolve your query.
Link - : [What is the proper pattern for nested schemas in Mongoose/MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413630/what-is-the-proper-pattern-for-nested-schemas-in-mongoose-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to achieve this.

1. First remove bookmarks
2. Add this

   ```
   ref: {  
       kind: String, // <-- Model Name post,complain
       item: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       refPath: 'ref.kind',
       fields: String,
       },
   },
   ```
3. When you want to fetch the records,you can use populate

   ```
   model.User.find({})
   .populate({ path: 'ref.item' })
   .then(data=>{console.log(data)})
   .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
   ```